# Ubuntu 22.04 boots to blank screen on the laptop with Intel integrated graphics

Tags: graphics, screen, intel

Recovery mode graphics mode helps. After putting it in suspend mode and waking it up screen is blank.
With connected external monitor kernel boot messages are displayed on external monitor, then they are both blank.
All updates are installed. The same applies to Ubuntu 20.04.
Ubuntu 22.04 was installed a year ago. Installation was possible with choosing safe mode graphics and unchecked download updates feature. The laptop is Irbis NB-665.

```
~$ uname -r
5.19.0-42-generic
~$ hwinfo --gfxcard
15: PCI 02.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)              
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: _Znp.w6tYiWWEn98
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:02.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Device Name: "Onboard IGD"
  Model: "Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x22b1 "Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0xf000 
  SubDevice: pci 0x02f3 
  Revision: 0x35
  Memory Range: 0x80000000-0x80ffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x90000000-0x9fffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xf000-0xf03f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 255 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d000022B1sv0000F000sd000002F3bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: i915 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i915"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

Primary display adapter: #15
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you edit your question to reflect whether this is a recent (new) Ubuntu installation, and if you checked the download feature during the installation. What is the make, model and year of your machine?

Comment: I see that this is an old question, but I seem to be having similar issues and am not sure if I should ask another question or not. I have Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 installed on a HP Elitebook laptop using the intel i915 graphics card driver. The install works fine, but sometime for reasons I am not entirely sure of when I try to wake it from sleeping the screen remains blank and I cannot find any way to get the screen to respond. The laptop appears to be on (e.g., the keyboard is lit), but the screen will not respond. Eventually I have to force power off and then power back on to wake the screen.

Comment: Should I use this question or create a new one?